# How to display only label and error for ActiveField in Yii2

Tags: php, yii, yii2

Please, tell me, how to display only label and error for field by ActiveField in Yii2?
I'm using Redactor and I want to display not only textarea, but also errors and label. Thanks.

The code example is given below.

```
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(); ?>

    <?php echo $form->errorSummary($model); ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'title')->textInput(['maxlength' => 255]) ?>

    <?php
    echo yii\imperavi\Widget::widget(
        [
            'model' => $model,
            'attribute' => 'text',
            'options' => [],
        ]
    );
    ?>
    <br />
    <div class="form-group">
        <?= Html::submitButton(
            $model->isNewRecord ? Yii::t('app', 'Create') : Yii::t('app', 'Update'),
            ['class' => $model->isNewRecord ? 'btn btn-success' : 'btn btn-primary']
        ) ?>
    </div>

    <?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
<?php 
$field = $form->field($model, 'username', ['options' => ['class' => 'form-group col-sm-6']]);
$field->template = "{label}\n{error}";  
echo $field->textInput(['maxlength' => 255]);
?>
```

Comment: You should use $template->template = "{label}\n{error}\n{input}"; otherwise you won't get input field.

Answer (score 18):

Try this. I have given the option for saperate

```
<?php
    use yii\helpers\Html;
    use yii\widgets\ActiveForm;

    $form =  \yii\widgets\ActiveForm::begin([
      'id' => 'form-id',
      'options' => ['class' => 'form-horizontal'],
      'enableClientValidation'=> true,
      'enableAjaxValidation'=> false,
      'validateOnSubmit' => true,
      'validateOnChange' => true,
      'validateOnType' => true,
      'action' => 'youractionurl',
      'validationUrl' => 'yourvalidationurl'
    ]);

    echo $form->field($model, 'fieldname')->begin();
        echo Html::activeLabel($model,'fieldname'); //label
        echo Html::activeTextInput($model, 'fieldname'); //Field
        echo Html::error($model,'fieldname', ['class' => 'help-block']); //error
    echo $form->field($model, 'fieldname')->end();
    \yii\widgets\ActiveForm::end(); 
?>
```

Comment: It does not validate on client side.

Comment: I was looking for this solution for a long time. I can confirm that client-side validation is working.

Comment: @RNKushwaha if you are using bootstrap active form, error need additional class to work: `Html::error($model, 'foobar', ['class' => 'help-block help-block-error'])`

Comment: I did this: `Html::tag("div", Html::error($model, "myfield", ['class' => 'help-block']), ['class' => 'has-error'])`

Answer (score 2):

It too some decision, but mistakes still aren't displayed.

```
$redactor = yii\imperavi\Widget::widget(
        [
            'model' => $model,
            'attribute' => 'text',
            'options' => [
                'minHeight' => 400,
            ],
        ]
    );   
$form->field($model, 'text', ['template' => "{error}\n{label}\n{hint}\n{$redactor}"])->textarea();
```